# Question about how to get image/coimage factorization in a preabelian category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, additive-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an additive category and assume that all finite limits and colimits exist. I am using the definition of the image and coimage of a morphism $f: A \longrightarrow B$ given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(category_theory)). I am able to show that if the category is also abelian, and hence all epimorphisms and monomorphisms are normal, then this definition is equivalent to the usual definition
$$
\text{im}(f) = \ker(\text{coker}(f)) \quad \text{and} \quad \text{coim}(f) = \text{coker}(\ker(f)).
$$
In that case, we have the usual coimage-image factorization
$$
A \longrightarrow \text{coim}(f) \stackrel{\bar{f}}\longrightarrow \text{im}(f) \longrightarrow B.
$$
However, I would like to show that such a factorization exists using the definition on Wikipedia I linked above, as long as my preabelian category has all finite limits and colimits. I think the key is in the existence of all equalizers, although I can't quite get it. Is someone able to point me in the right direction, or even tell me if it is in fact true?

Thanks

Comment: You can get an image-coimage factorization using only the assumption of finite limits and colimits, and nothing else: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/image#comparison_of_regular_images_and_coimages

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've had a look at the proof now, and there are a few claims I'm not sure I see why are true. In particular, I'm not sure I understand how the definition in terms of equalizing the cokernel pair is equivalent to the definition I am using.

Comment: In particular, it seems like the result given there only holds for the regular image and coimage, and there is no reason to think that every image or coimage in a preabelian category is regular is there?

Comment: I guess not, but the regular image and coimage are so well-behaved (in particular, they can be defined using only finite limits and colimits, and the factorization above always exists as long as they do) that you might as well just use them.